# use of ? in sh script

Tags: bash, shell, tar

When I went through some shell scripts I came across the following line of codes

```
FILENAME=/home/user/test.tar.gz
tar -zxvf $FILENAME
RES=$?FILENAME
if [ $RES -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "TAR extract success
fi
```

I want to know

1. What is the use of '?' mark in front of the variable(RES=$?FILENAME).
2. How to check whether tar extracted successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard (POSIX-ish) shells, `$?` is a [special parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters). Even Bash's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) doesn't document an alternative meaning.

In the context, `$?FILENAME` might expand to `0FILENAME` if the previous command succeeded, and perhaps `1FILENAME` if it failed.

Since there's a numeric comparison requested (`-eq`) the value `0FILENAME` might convert to `0` and then compare OK.  However, on my system (Mac OS X 10.10.5, Bash 3.2.57) attempting:

```
if [ 0FILE -eq 0 ]; then echo equal; fi
```

yields the error `-bash: [: 0FILE: integer expression expected`.

So, adding the `FILENAME` after the `$?` is unorthodox at best (or confusing, or even, ultimately, wrong).

Answer (score 1):

By `default`, the `exit status` of a function is the exit status returned by the **last command** in the function. After the function executes, you use the standard `$?` variable to `determine` the **exit status of the function**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testing the exit status of a function
my_function() {
echo "trying to display a non-existent file"
ls -l no_file
}
echo "calling the function: "
my_function
echo "The exit status is: $?"
$
$ ./test4
testing the function:
trying to display a non-existent file
ls: badfile: No such file or directory
The exit status is: 1
```

To check if tar successfully executed or not use

```
tar xvf "$tar" || exit 1
```